# Regex help, data from an attribute within a subtag of a tag

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing

so i'd just like to quickly put out there that regex is a suitable solution for this problem, the html it is parsing is and will always be formatted the same.

The particular piece of html I am interested in parsing looks similar to the following

```
<a href="" target="" onCick=""><img style="" onmouseover="" onmouseout="" src="" alt="" /></a>
```

I am interested in pulling the 'src' and 'alt' tags out of that string. Regex really confuses me to the point that I don't really understand what i'm doing with it. so real help would be appreciated. Would mean alot, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Which language are you using? Regexp dialects have some minor differences.

Either way, for JavaScript you could use

```
var match = /src="(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)"/.exec(pieceOfHTML);
// match[1] should be the src, match[2] the alt
```

or for Python,

```
match = re.search(r'src="(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)', pieceOfHTML)
# match.group(1) and match.group(2) respectively
```

*EDIT* re comments:

```
<a href=".*?"\s+target=".*?"\s+onCick=".*?"><img style=".*?"\s+onmouseover=".*?" onmouseout=".*?"\s+src="(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)"
```

should be a decent regexp to match only the pattern required, with lenience regarding whitespace.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've tried regex like this before, but it is not applicable in this case. There are other <img> tags on the page, but not within <a> tags. I am not interested in those, I am only interested in the ones contained within <a>. Which is what has confused me.